# MongoDB C# driver update to 2.19.2 throws "InvalidCastException"

Tags: c#, mongodb, enums, mongodb-query, aggregate

I'm having a linq query which fetches the enum data from database and it throws the following exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.Int32Serializer' to type 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Serializers.IEnumUnderlyingTypeSerializer

Actual code

```cs
Car = (Vehicle)project.Car
```

tried of casting

```cs
Car = (Vehicle)(int)(Vehicle)project.Car
```